# Как создать приложение на Python, которое будет работать в фоновом режиме?

Tags: python

передо мной стоит задача: написать приложение(под Windows) на python(tkinter, kivy, PyQT, pySide, PyGTK, wxPython, на чём не знаю, но обращая внимание на мой вопрос вы могли бы подсказать на чём делать), которое будет перетаскивать файлы с одной директории в другую(это будут сертификаты .cer .crl). При всём при этом программа должна работать в фоновом режиме(как антивирус), т.е. я открыл скомпилированный экзешник, вылезло окно, я нажал нужное мне вкладку, забил путь откуда файлы берутся и куда кладутся, затем окно закрыл, но оно работало бы на фоне(не свёрнуто, а именно на фоне), чтобы проверять через определенное время(допустим каждый день) истёк ли сертификат, и если истёк, то вылетало бы сообщение на рабочий стол(типо братан, срок годности твоей банки с майонезом истек, купи новую). Похоже на работу антивируса, открываем, забиваем нужные данные, закрываем, а как только он находит вирус, он делает оповещение. Я сам на плюсах пишу и web занимаюсь, на python особо не рублю, но задача написать на нём, буду благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Все перечисленные вами технологии позволяют скрыть окно. Если вы их изучали, это не должно для вас быть проблемой

Comment: Я выше указал, что на python не программирую и никогда не создавал десктопные приложения, поэтому обратился за помощью сюда.

Comment: `Qt` дожен быть для вас родным http://doc.qt.io/

Comment: @Redial ну вы в вопросе уже перечислили всё то, что мы вам могли бы ответить. Берите и изучайте, мы тут уже ни при чём :)

Comment: Понял, а как сделать чтобы приложение работало в фоновом режиме и открывалось в окне только по нажатию (там на экзешник например)?

Comment: Виндовые сервисы это тот ещё ад) особенно на питоне